# Having issue with ExpandableListView. The listView is not being populated in fragment

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement a ExpandableListView in a fragment. The updated test list are not being shown in the layout view. I tried same code as new project (in activity it seems working), but I couldn't figure out the issue in fragment.
The view are not being generated.I've pasted the code I've been trying. What could be the actual issue here? Please let me know where I went wrong in fragment.

**EDIT (2/2/2017)**
The actual issue I figured out was,

I've been using ExpandableListView inside ScrollView at the first place,

```
           <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollFragHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

           ...........other layouts ......

                <ExpandableListView
                            android:id="@+id/resHubExpandableListView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:groupIndicator="@null"
                            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
          </ScrollView>
```

I had to give layout_width of list view fixed height to view all the view of it.
I used wrap_content at the beginning, but it didn't expanded the listview as it should have been.

I've used LayoutParam to set list view's height for now.

Is there any other default way to display all the elements once adapter is set?

Thank you.

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resourceHubTitleHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/login"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Franchisee Emails"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

layout_list_item.xml

```
 <!--resource hub title/date-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resourceTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Franchisee Agreement"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date: "
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resourceDateUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DD/MMM/YYYY"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ExpandableListView Adapter:

```
public class ResHubExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mResHubList;
ArrayList<String> mResHubHeaderList;
Context mContext;

public ResHubExpandableListAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mResHubFiles
        , ArrayList<String> resHubHeader) {
    this.mResHubList = mResHubFiles;
    this.mResHubHeaderList = resHubHeader;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mResHubHeaderList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mResHubList.get(mResHubHeaderList.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mResHubHeaderList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mResHubList.get(mResHubHeaderList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (row == null || row.getTag() == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_hub_list_header, null);
        GeneralUtil.Log("rzenks getGroupView", "getGroupView at position: " + groupPosition);
    }
    TextView resourceHubTitleHeader = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.resourceHubTitleHeader);
    resourceHubTitleHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return row;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (row == null || row.getTag() == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_hub_list_item, null);
        GeneralUtil.Log("rzenks getChildView", "getChildView at position: " + groupPosition);
    }
    TextView resourceTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.resourceTitle);
    resourceTitle.setText(childText);

    return row;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}}
```

My Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //new tab addition
    mResourceHubMain = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.resourceHubMain);
    mResHubExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.resHubExpandableListView);

    // New Tab list data view
    prepareExpandListData();
    mExpandableListAdapter = new ResHubExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), resHubList, resHubHeaderList);
    mResHubExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
    }
```